# Unity raycast is not returning anything when using IL2CPP

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a mobile game where I check what object was hit by getting input from touch and casting a ray from camera to that touch using Physics.Raycast. Everything works fine in editor and Unity Remote, but when I building it and playing on a real device raycasts simply just don't return anything.

I've tried swithing off "Strip engine code" under Player Settings, but it didn't work for me

```cs
public void TouchPress(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Vector2 touchPosition = touchPositionAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y, 1.86f + Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.transform.position.z)));

        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, position - Camera.main.transform.position, out hit, 10f))
        {
        //this is where I can't get any debug.log
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.layer == 6)
            {
                prop = hit.collider.gameObject;
                rb = prop.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

                rb.useGravity = false;
                rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

                touchOffset = prop.transform.position - position;

                holding = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you know it is specifically the raycast failing and not maybe something in your code handling the result / user input?

Comment: Firstly, I am using Unity’s new input system. In my code there is OnTouchPress method where I get position of a touch, then convert it to world position. Next, I check if raycast from camera to that position is hitting something. So I’ve tried debugging my code. In editor it’s working fine and raycast returns an object it hit, but debugging a build on phone showed me that raycast returns nothing.

Comment: In general I would try and rather go for `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touchPosition)` and use this for the raycast .. besides that it might depend on how exactly the TouchPress action is set up

Comment: @derHugo I've tried this and it didn't worked. However I've maneged to fix this. The problem was in Mesh that I have imported from Blender. I had to check "Read/Write" box under the import settings of FBX. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've maneged to fix this. The problem was in Mesh that I have imported from Blender. As far as I understand, in the build version of my project there was an issue with colliders, so after doing some research on that I found the solution. I had to check "Read/Write" box under the import settings of FBX.